# How to normalize data in ember.js

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have related data `Attribute` --> `Values` in `meta` section.

`pushPayload` works fine

`this.store.pushPayload(res.products.get('meta.attributes'))`

But I need push into model only new data, so I try to normalize:

```
model.set('attributes', this.store.normalize('attribute', res.products.get('meta.attributes')));
```

During normalize I got error:

```
string.js:63 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
    at Cache.func (string.js:63)
    at Cache.get (ember-metal.js:2611)
    at decamelize (string.js:100)
    at Cache.func (string.js:11)
    at Cache.get (ember-metal.js:2611)
    at Object.dasherize (string.js:104)
    at normalizeModelName (-private.js:560)
    at Class.modelNameFromPayloadKey (json-api.js:352)
    at Class._extractType (json-api.js:338)
    at Class.normalize (json-api.js:379)
```

So what is the error here? I don't want to write loop on `meta.attributes` and use `peekRecord`

**codesandbox example**: [codesandbox.io/s/n5l1xw656l](http://codesandbox.io/s/n5l1xw656l)

Answer (score 1):

When you `get` data for a relationship, it is async code that returns a promise. See this section of the Ember.js Guides, [Relationships as Promises](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/models/relationships/#toc_relationships-as-promises). I suspect that at the time of the set, the attributes records are undefined because the promise has not resolved.

Try this instead and see if it helps:

```
res.products.get('meta.attributes').then((records) => {
   model.set('attributes', this.store.normalize('attribute', records));
})
```

Comment: I got error: `TypeError: products.get(...).then is not a function`. res - is just an object with keys `data` an `meta`. Meta contain: `attributes.data`, `attributes.included`. So I try to normalize data in `meta.attributes`.

Comment: Sorry to hear this is still not working for you @Ivanov. Please add your models and a sample response json to your question, or create an Ember Twiddle/codesandbox that shows this error, so we can better help you

Comment: The question still actual, may be add some additional data for better understanding